# How to set up Python for .NET with Python 2.6.1?

Tags: python

The "final" release of Python for .NET ([link](http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=162464&package_id=183296&release_id=537499)) isn't pre-compiled for Python 2.6. I don't have a problem changing the compilation symbol to PYTHON26 as specified in the docs, the solution rebuilds just fine, but when attempting to import the CLR, I get an error indicating that python26.dll is missing. Anyone know how to build this file? It doesn't seem to be part of the solution, but I might be missing something obvious.

Comment: Have you checked IronPython instead?

Answer (score 3):

I managed it by following [these instructions](http://feihonghsu.blogspot.com/2008/02/installing-pythonnet-20-alpha-2-on.html) by one Feihong Hsu.

I notice now that the author has made a [follow-up post](http://feihonghsu.blogspot.com/search/label/python.net) that may be important too if you're using SP1.